# My XMLHttpRequest wrapper is breaking the process

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, userscripts

I am adding functionality to an existing site through user scripts.  After clicking on a certain button, the site performs an XMLHttpRequest operation.  It then dynamically adds HTML to the body, which includes the button I need to click, and creates a modal within the page.  In order to automate the next click, I have to watch for the XHR event to complete, look for the expected button to be generated, then click it.  I have successfully added an event listener to the XMLHttpRequest prototype.  Different iterations of this wrapper have worked, but none with proper performance.  Since I am modifying the prototype, the solution must be fast.  The latest version, below, is fast but it started to break the XHR request.  The website reports 'AJAX Error' in the console.

```
    (function(open) {
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
            this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4){
                console.log("completed");
                try{
                    var elm = document.getElementById('avsaddressupdate_submit_btn');
                    console.log(elm);
                    elm.click();

                }
                catch(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
            }, false);

            open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: why are you using try catch and not just checking to see if the button exists before clicking? `if (elm) { elm.click(); }` Also seems weird to hijack the whole XHR object to do this.

Comment: Move the open call before you set readystatechange and that should probably fix it.

Comment: Moving the open call before setting readtstatechange did not help.

Comment: What is the error exactly? "Ajax Error" does not give us any details...where is that thrown?

Comment: "AJAX Error" is posted to the console by the site's custom js. It must indicate that the XHR times out, or some other issue.  The point is that it works fine without my getElementById.  I need a better solution.